# How to create a custom button in Storyboard TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an app that uses a tableview to set some user preferences.

Here are the buttons, png images.  But I want the user to tap a cell and have something appear in the white part of the button.  For example, for the location one, the location icon should turn red!  Or for the driveThru one, the white box should display a check of X inside.

Here are the buttons:

[image: Button1]
[image: Button2]
What would be the best way to have the buttons change upon tap?

Comment: Are the buttons inside the cell ? Where are these two buttons ? Please add more  details to your question it's quite vague.

Comment: Yes the buttons have been dropped into the cell inside storyboard.  Thus there is now a tableviewcell with a imageview in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add code to the `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`method called within your tableview delegate that updates your buttons after touch events within a tableviewcell, and you could use a logic gate to determine which button should be updated.  You would need to make your buttons instance variables/properties so that you could refer to them within methods other than the ones that created them.  If your button images are png, you will have to create another png with the change you want and then substitute the changed png as the imageview of your button(assuming that is how you did it).Hope this helps

Comment: Ok right now i have the image set from storyboard.  My image is named image.jpg and image2.jpg.  The one set in storyboards is image.jpg.  How do I get a reference to the cell's image view.image in order to check if its image.jpg then set it to image2.jpg, else...?

Comment: i'm a little confused-are these actual UIButtons?  or are they simply png files inside of imageviews inside of the tableviewcell?  the two situations would be handled quite differently-and remember a tableviewcell has its own imageview